# Why isn't discover software manager able to load applications in Arch LInux?

Tags: arch-linux, kde, application, plasma5

Why isn't the discover software manager loading any applications in Arch Linux? This is what discover is saying:

> Discover currently cannot be used to install any apps because none of its app backends are available. Please report this error to your distribution.

Please have a look at the screenshot:

[image]

But I am able to download packages through terminal. Please help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to install one of the backends first using [pacman](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/pacman). You need `packagekit-qt5` or `packagekit-qt6` (for KDE 6) for "normal" packages, `flatpak` for Flatpaks and `fwupd` for firmware updates.

for KDE 5:

```
# pacman -S packagekit-qt5 flatpak fwupd
```

for KDE 6:

```
# pacman -S packagekit-qt6 flatpak fwupd
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `packagekit-qt5` is not recommended by Arch or Plasma. Anything other than `pacman` is usually going to have the potential to create partial upgrades, which are not supported.

Comment: If you updated to KDE version 6 you need `packagekit-qt6` for things to work.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the answer.